# Angular ng-animate when using the same ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-animate

In parent template I'm specifying ui-view where the child view should appear, I also include animation, like this:

```
<div class="am-fade-and-slide-bottom" ui-view></div>
```

So I want animation to appear when something has been put ten in this view. And it works! And if I remove that ui-view (well, go to the previous state when using ui-router), I get animation of hiding that view.

The problem is, that when I'm changing the content of ui-view, I get repeated animations of hiding-and-showing, though I want to to stay without animation this time (as I have loading indicator on the template which goes inside ui-view).

How would I do that?

---

This is class `.am-fade-and-slide-bottom` from the [Angular Motion library](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-motion/blob/master/src/fade-and-slide/fade-and-slide.less#L72):

```
.am-fade-and-slide-bottom {

  animation-duration: @fade-and-slide-duration;
  animation-timing-function: @fade-and-slide-timing-function;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;

  &.am-fade-and-slide-bottom-add, &.ng-hide-remove, &.ng-move {
    animation-name: fadeAndSlideFromBottom;
  }
  &.am-fade-and-slide-bottom-remove, &.ng-hide {
    animation-name: fadeAndSlideToBottom;
  }

  &.ng-enter {
    visibility: hidden;
    animation-name: fadeAndSlideFromBottom;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    &.ng-enter-active {
      visibility: visible;
      animation-play-state: running;
    }
  }
  &.ng-leave {
    animation-name: fadeAndSlideToBottom;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    &.ng-leave-active {
      animation-play-state: running;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the CSS for the animation please?

Comment: It's Angular Motion library: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-motion/blob/master/src/fade-and-slide/fade-and-slide.less#L72